# Small time adjustments with adjtimex

Tags: c, linux, time, kernel

I have a Linux system where I need to make small periodical adjustments to the system time to track an external time source, but I want to avoid date/time jumps.

I thought of using the `adjtimex()` kernel function (see: [adjtimex(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/adjtimex), [adjtimex(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adjtimex)), however I have some doubts:

1. What is exactly the difference between the offset and singleshot modes?
2. What is the acceptable parameter range? I am asking because:

   - [adjtimex(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adjtimex) mentions that the argument for `--offset` must be in the -512000...512000 range (so it would only be able to correct for +/- 0.5s), and does not mention any value for `--singleshot`
   - [adjtimex(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/adjtimex) mentions a range -131071..+131071 which would apparently apply to both modes
   - In my tests (using the `adjtimex` command line utility) none of these limits seem to apply

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Please refer to the [Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) for Linux man pages. They're more likely to be up to date. The comments indicate the implemented logic should follow [RFC 1305](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1305.txt).)

For the implementation details, just browse the Linux kernel sources.  The `adjtimex()` syscall is defined in [kernel/time.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time.c); look for `SYSCALL_DEFINE.*(adjtimex,`.

`adjtimex()` itself calls `do_adjtimex()` defined in [kernel/time/timekeeping.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timekeeping.c). Basic range checking is done in `ntp_validate_timex()` defined in [kernel/time/ntp.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/ntp.c).

As to your specific questions:

1. If you use `ADJ_OFFSET_SINGLESHOT`, `adjtimex()` behaves as `adjtime()`, and you can only use the `.offset` field. Depending on the size and sign of the adjustment, the NTP clock is speeded up or slowed down for a short while, until the desired offset is achieved; then the NTP clock rate is reverted back to original. You cannot use any other mode flags with it.

   `ADJ_SETOFFSET` adds `.time` to the current time; immediately moving the clock forward.

   `ADJ_OFFSET` also adjusts NTP clock rate to achieve the desired offset in a reasonable time, so the effects should be the same as in single-shot mode. However, you can use the other `ADJ_` mode flags in the same call, too.

   Edited after the comment from Grodriguez:

   `ADJ_OFFSET` has an effect only if the offset is thought to be good, i.e. that the clock state is phase-locked, `STA_PLL`. Typically, an NTP daemon will change the state to frequency-locked (`STA_FLL`) if the sampling interval is long, or the NTP daemon had a bad sample.

   To use `ADJ_OFFSET`, your program should probably use mode mode `ADJ_OFFSET|ADJ_STATUS`, and set `.status=STA_PLL`. This causes the current time to be set to the reference time, so that the offset is counted with respect to current system time, and also enables the clock offset adjustment.
2. In the kernel sources, the `MAXPHASE` constant (in [include/linux/timex.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/timex.h)) defines the offset limit. Currently, it is in nanoseconds, and specifies a half second; larger values (in magnitude) are quietly limited to half a second, without any error.

   In Linux kernels prior to 2.6.26, the limit was smaller (±131071µs). The new limit was added in [May 2008](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/kernel/time/ntp.c?id=ee9851b218b8bafa22942b5404505ff3d2d34324).

   (The change in the limit was communicated to Linux man-page maintainer, Michael Kerrisk, [in June 2009](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=124411407910043&w=4) but apparently the adjtimex(2) man page was never updated to reflect this change. I don't think the suggested wording was clear enough, though.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The difference between the single shot and offset modes is still not clear to me, though. From the sources of the adjtimex utility (http://adjtimex.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.29-2.2/adjtimex_8c_source.html) I see that the `--offset` option uses the `ADJ_OFFSET` mode. However in my tests, `--singleshot` work as advertised, but `--offset` seems to do nothing. Any hints?

Comment: Interesting! `ADJ_OFFSET` ends up being handled by calling `ntp_update_offset()`, which ignores the call unless the clock status is `STA_PLL` (phase-locked). I'll amend my answer with the details.

Comment: Uhm, are you sure about this last bit? Looking at `__do_adjtimex` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/ntp.c#L555) it seems that if `ADJ_OFFSET` is set, *both* `ntp_update_offset()` and `ntp_update_frequency()` will be called. Note that none of the existing `adjtimex` command line utilities set `ADJ_STATUS` when you use the `--offset` switch (they just set `ADJ_OFFSET`)

Comment: @Grodriguez: Yes. `ntp_update_offset()` applies the offset, but only if clock status is already `STA_PLL`. If `ADJ_STATUS` is also set, it will set the clock status before that call. That part is clear in the code. `ntp_update_frequency()` updates the clock frequency, to apply whatever gradual changes are currently targeted; it does not modify target clock changes. `ADJ_OFFSET_ONESHOT` modifies the target offset (in `__do_adjtimex()`) just before the call, regardless of clock mode. `ntp_update_offset()` adjusts both tick rate and offset but only if clock is already phase-locked.

Comment: @Grodriguez: `adjtimex` is orphaned since [2011](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636404), last updated in 2010 (origin in 1995). [`ntp_update_offset()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/kernel/time/ntp.c?id=ee9851b218b8bafa22942b5404505ff3d2d34324) is from 2008. `adjtimex` command line utility is not something I'd pattern my utility on. An actively maintained utility should certainly have at least an option to force the kernel clock state (to phase-locked or frequency-locked).